# Error 2042 ("N/A") in Excel VLookup() Worksheet Function

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Need some help to figure out strange VBA `VLOOKUP` `Type Missmatch` error. The code is really simple, since sss0 is a random number and all I want is to find closest value in a range (sheet 'BMD_CDF', Range("A2:B999")). In the spreadsheet, I set format for Sheets("BMD_CDF").Range("A2:B999") to scientific already...

```
Dim LookUp_Range As Range
Dim sss0 As Double
Set LookUp_Range = Sheets("BMD_CDF").Range("A2:B999")

sss0=Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Rnd(), 0.005)
Debug.Print Application.VLookup(sss0, LookUp_Range, 2, 0)
```

#### ERROR MSG

[image]

#### What Range looks like

[image]

Comment: (a) Which line gives the type mismatch?  (b) I would have expected your `Debug.Print` to usually print `Error 2042` because it will be unlikely that a random number will appear **exactly** in a sample of only 998 values.

Comment: @SMeaden `Debug.Print` will automatically handle the error type, which is why it is printing `Error 2042` when not matched.

Comment: @SMeaden, thanks for the suggestion. returned value is `True`. but I am not sure how to trace the error...

Comment: @YowE3K, error code is Runtime error 13

Comment: @YowE3K, it is that `Debug.Print ` line

Comment: The OP's original code worked for me - will now try the revised code.

Comment: @SMeaden, I tried to pass range.value, but failed.

Comment: New code works for me too - `Debug.Print` prints `Error 2042`.  `Debug.Print` should be able to cope with a `Variant/Error`, so I can't think of anything that `VLookup` could return that would cause a type mismatch.

Comment: Why not `Debug.Print Application.VLookup(sss0, LookUp_Range, 2, -1)`?  FALSE=0 , TRUE=-1 in VBA

Comment: Try creating a dummy `Variant` value (`Dim temp As Variant`) and then use it instead of `Debug.Print` (i.e. `temp = Application.VLookup(...`) and look at the value of `temp` in a watch window.

Comment: @SMeaden Yeah - an exact match for a random number is ... strange.  But it doesn't explain the type mismatch.  I wouldn't expect a type mismatch unless the result was being put into a numeric or string variable.

Comment: @YowE3K, the error code is `2042`

Comment: @YowE3K: I agree Excel VBA reports #N/A as 2042  And I cannot recreate type mismatch error 13.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a type mismatch on the `Debug.Print`.  That should handle the error code happily.  But if you were doing something like `Dim x As Double : x = Application.VLookup(sss0, LookUp_Range, 2, 0)` **that** would give a type mismatch.

Comment: What version of Excel is this?

Comment: @YowE3K, EXCEL 2013 on WINDOWS 10 64 bit. ANd `temp = Application.VLookup(0.015, LookUp_Range, 2, 0)` gave me ERROR 2042, in which temp is defined as a variant.

Comment: @tao.hong : And if you make the last line `Debug.Print temp` ?

Comment: @SMeaden, yes, and it printed out `Error 2042`

Comment: So the Type mismatch went away?  Cool.

Comment: @YowE3K SMeaden, but it did not returned the desired result... I tested using an existing value and result is 2042

Comment: @tao.hong: you want closest match pass =-1 in final argument, if you pass 0 you get exact match.

Comment: @tao.hong the reason you aren't getting the desired result is (a) you are doing an **exact** match, and (b) [once you fix (a)] you are searching for a number between 0 and 1 in a set of values that starts at 6.

Comment: @YowE3K, I assume, the vlookup could find something in Col B

Comment: @tao.hong `VLookup` looks for a value in the **first** column and then returns a value from the same row but the specified column (you specified column 2)

Comment: @tao.hong If you want to return the value in the first column based on a search on the second column, you either need to do an Index / Match, or switch the columns.

Comment: @YowE3K, yes, I will switch the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Error 2042` ("N/A") seems to be caused by the fact that the value returned by the Excel Worksheet function:

```
Aplication.WorksheetFunction.Max(Rnd(), 0.005)
```

which is always less than 1 will never get into specified range of values (>6) in `column A`. For testing purpose, try to substitute it with any number in that range of values in `Column A`, for example, `sss0 =6.15` and modify the VLOOKUP() statement as following:

```
Debug.Print Application.VLookup(sss0, LookUp_Range, 2, 1)
```

(where 1 stands for logical `TRUE`) to get it working, i.e. finding the closest value (not exact match) as per your definition.

Hope this may help.